# Is there any way to enumerate "variables made special by use in arguments"?

Tags: manipulate, expression-manipulation, symbols, variable

I want to create a way to enumerate teal color coded variables in my `Manipulate` function. Specifically, I would like the user to input a number so that my function takes this number and produces a teal color coded variable with respect to the given numerical value.

For example, if I were to input `1` into the function, I want to produce the teal colored variable `xInt1`. If the user inputs `2`, the teal colored variable should be `xInt2`. So on. The variables `xInt1` and `xInt2` both live in the `Manipulate` function.

Is this possible? If so, how? Thank you!

EDIT: Here is a very basic example:

```
q[n_] := Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

Currently, the above function is not defined with respect to `n`. However, I am interested in enumerating `a` so that when the user inputs a numerical value (for example `1`) for `n`, the `Manipulate` function is defined over `"a"<>"n"` (in example, `a1`). Thank you!

Comment: I supplied a very basic example explaining my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q[n_] := Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[x (1 + # x)], {x, 0, 6}], {#, 0, 2}
] & @@ ToExpression["xInt" <> ToString[n], StandardForm, Unevaluated]
```